# Continuous Integration using TFS with VM for Build

Tags: continuous-integration, tfsbuild

What is the best way to configure a Continuous integration ?

We have multiple Teams developing Projects in VB, C# web based projects, Windows based Project etc.

Trying to setup VM for Build. Since each project requires lot of dependent installation and even different .NET frame work, i though about using project Specific VM where the Build should Run. Is that a feasible scenario. Is it possible to configure TFS to Instantiate a Particular VM and then run the build on that VM and if successful Deploy it to specified machine other then VM that it built on.

Any articles/Links to setup such environment for Continuous integration is appreciated.

Trying to remain on Microsoft Software, but will consider other option if they are really easy to implement

Comment: When you say that each project requires a lot of dependant installations, do the dependancies need to be installed or just on the file system for referencing purposes?

Comment: They need to be installed

Answer (score 0):

you can use Octopus for Continuous Integration and Delivery purposes. you can define environments in which your software installed. you can easily define your release steps.